# What is the difference between utility function and characteristic function

Tags: game-theory, utility, social-welfare

I read that normative theories such as social welfare and game theory have as tasks computing the peoples' (average) *utility function* in the first case, and the *characteristic function* in cooperative games with transferable utility. Moreover, in game theory the characteristic function constitutes "the game" itself.

I appreciate very much any gentle intuitive explanation of the difference between these two concepts.

(Edited: Thanks for the comment; the question is edited)

Comment: I disagree with some of these claims. I don't think this is the main task of either social welfare or game theory. Also you seem to be thinking of cooperative game theory which is very distinct from non-cooperative game theory so it may be worth making the distinction.